# How to block from sideloading apps (ipa) in iOS devices.?

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect, ios

I want to block sideloading the apps (ipa) to my iOS devices (iPhone, iPod, iPad). I googled about it and to my surprise, everyone was asking questions on how to sideload the apps.

So, if anyone could help me in identifying this, it would really be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without the device being jailbroken or having a development provisioning profile installed, there's absolutely no difference between an app installed via the App Store or via "sideloading", except that one might be able to install an old version of an App Store app. Or possibly an app which the developer removed from the app store by choice. It's simply not possible to install any app that's not originally from the app store via "sideloading" without it being configured for development as all applications must have a valid App Store code signature. If you want to block installation of *all* apps, you can create a MDM profile with Apple Configurator with this restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I dont want to block all the apps from installing. I only need to restrict the apps installing from sideloading. I should able to download apps from app store. Is there any possibility for that.

@ Geoff Nixon

Comment: Yes — that is the default configuration. By default, the only apps that can be sideloaded are Apps downloaded from the App Store. So **it is already configured how you want!**